# Excluding hidden tabstops

Tags: python, tabs, pywin32, tabstop

I am trying to extract the tab stops of a paragraph and I am using win32 and this line of code to loop through each tabstops.
`for tab in para_range.ParagraphFormat.TabStops:`

But even there is no single visual tabstop in the paragraph it is detecting multiple tabstops (in my case count = 13). Why?

Comment: Please add some sample data and a bit more of your code, so that others can reproduce what you see.

Comment: I am using python with win32 library to extract the TabStop from msword even when there are no tab stop in the given paragraph (I checked the word  tabstops too but there is also no tabstop) it is finding them and looping over them. I want to know Why it is showing tabstop even there are none?